# PullRequests in Github

Tags: github

I have put up a PR using `branch1` and working on another feature on `branch2`.. When I put up a PR using `branch2` all files from `branch1` appear too. How do I rectify this such that the work in `branch2` is independent and doesn't have files from `branch1` ?

Comment: How did you create `branch2`?

Comment: From `master` branch

Comment: Are you trying to merge into `master`?

Comment: Nope.. Trying to keep them independent.. But when I put up the PR using `branch2` all the files just appeared.. Not sure how to rectify this

Answer (score -1):

You need to return to the master version where there is no branch1. then when you pull from master and create branch2,there will be no files from branch 1.