# Azure Pullrequest does not update 'based on commit' on two consecutively pullrequests

Tags: git, azure-devops

Let's say I make a feature branch *Feature1* from master branch is currently on commit A.
Then I make two commits in *Feature1* branch B and C.
Now I make a pull request PR1 (don't merge).

Then a branch *Feature2* is done dependent on commit C, a commit D is done on this branch, and pull request PR2 is created.

Branches and pull requests picture:
[image: Branches and pull requests picutre]

Azure now displays everything correct on the two pull requests.

PR1:

```
 Commits: Shows B and C -> correct
 Files: Shows diff from A to C (Based on commit A) -> correct
```

PR2:

```
 Commits: Shows B, C and D -> correct
 Files: Shows correct diff from A to D (Based on commit A) -> correct
```

Now complete PR1 using fast forward.

The problem is now:

PR2:

```
 Commits: Shows D -> correct
 Files: Show still the diff from A to D (Based on commit A) -> **unexpected**
```

Expectation would be Azure should update the 'Files' diff and show only C to D (Based on commit C).

How can I tell Azure to change the 'Based on commit' pointing to C after complete PR1 on PR2?
Of course I can choose 'View merge changes' from Menu, but in this case also the 'Files' tab should only show the merge changes in my expectation (only C to D).

I think this question is the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47583849/pullrequests-in-github), but this question was not clearly asked / answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the right side of the PR screen, next to the complete button, there is a 3 dots menu, with an option called "[Restart Merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/complete-pull-requests?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#check-merge-changes)". Choosing that option should update the view as you expect. Note this happens automatically any time you change the target branch or push new changes to your branch, but it does not happen automatically when the target branch gets updated because it would potentially need to happen far too often, and in some repos it would slow everyone down.